# netcat not returning inside docker

Tags: docker, netcat

Simple scenario: a normal docker container linked to redis with a mounted volume containing an `appendonly.aof` file to fill up redis.:

```
docker run --rm -it --link redis:redis -v `pwd`:/data ubuntu:16.04 bash
```

I want to use `netcat` to fill up redis (I install `netcat` after attaching to the container):

```
cat data/appendonly.aof | nc redis 6379
```

I get `+OK`s from redis server, however nc doesn't exit and just hangs there. This works under normal Linux/Unix environment with no problem and I don't seem to find out why it get stuck in a docker container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `-q` flag to have `nc` quit *N* seconds after EOF on stdin.

Compare:

```
echo PING | nc redis 6379
```

With:

```
echo PING | nc -q0 redis 6379
```

With:

```
echo PING | nc -q1 redis 6379
```

In my environment, the first hangs as you describe, the second exits *before* it gets a response from the server, and the third shows me the `+PONG` response from redis.

This is obviously not ideal because you may not know in advance how long redis will take to respond, so you may have to play with timing a little bit and then cross your fingers.

I notice that the NMAP version of netcat (`ncat`, https://nmap.org/ncat/) seems to behave "out of the box" in a more sane fashion:

```
[root@dc12870502f9 /]# echo PING | ncat redis 6379
+PONG
```

Comment: I used `-w` flag to timeout, however both my solution and yours (as you mentioned it yourself) are not really satisfactory and I still don't know why it doesn't return. +1 for ncat suggestion!

Comment: `ncat` for sure solves the problem. I'd give this question a couple of day to see if anyone knows why `nc` fails in docker.